# Incorrect database name `` after mysql@8 upgrade

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0

After MySQL upgrade we ran into a breaking change as we have some really strange queries like this one:

```
use somedatabase;
SELECT * FROM `Table` where ``.`Table`.`id` = 1
```

With MySQL@5 this query runs without any issue, uses `somedatabase` as the actual database.

With MySQL@8 the same query throws a `Incorrect database name ''`.

I didn't find anything mentioning this behaviour change in upgrade docs. Is there any way to force MySQL@8 to treat empty database name as the currently selected one?

(Yes, I know the best would be to fix those queries)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this issue has anything to do with the version, then is seems to be something that has been "fixed" (in your case: "broken") by the developers of MySQL.

If you consult the MySQL Documentation for [Identifier Qualifiers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) in the version [8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html) and then switch to the same documentation for version [5.7](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/identifier-qualifiers.html), then you can find this bit of information:

> ...
> The syntax `.tbl_name` means the table `tbl_name` in the **default database**.
>
> **Note**
> This syntax is **deprecated as of MySQL 5.7.20**; ***expect it to be removed in a future version of MySQL.***
> ...

It seems like the option to have a default database in the Identifier Qualifers was removed somewhere between 5.7.20 and the current 8.0 version. You might find it in the [release notes 5.7x](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-0.html) for one of the versions in between. And then again you might not find it.

#### Conclusion

MySQL warned in advance, that this feature would be removed. It seems like it has now been effectively removed, without the option to revert back to the < 5.7.19 syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
use database;
    ^^^^^^^^  -- some name you made up

SELECT * FROM `Table` where ``.`Table`.`id` = 1
                            ^^  -- not valid database name
```

Note these syntaxes for referring to a column:

```
db_name.table_name.col_name
        table_name.col_name
                   col_name
```

In each case, backtics (``) may be optionally around each component.  The backtics are important when the name is also a keyword.  New versions add new keywords, thereby invalidating old scripts that don't have backtics until you add backtics.

As to how that occurred in an upgrade, I can't tell.  Do you really have a database with the keyword "database"?  Did you previously have just backtics for the database name?  What script did the upgrade?